# setLineNumber facing problems

Tags: java

Is there any alternative for SetLineNumber or to skip lines while reading a large file in java?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  Unless an index has been prepared beforehand, the only way to skip to line N of a file is to read the file from the start, counting the lines as you read them.  This is a consequence of the fact that text files are modeled (and represented) by the operating system, and by the Java I/O classes as a sequence of characters (or bytes) rather than a sequence of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not line but [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) [skip(bytes)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29) method exist

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("asd.txt"));
fis.skip(10);
fis.read();
```

or you can read with [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) [.readLine()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("asd.txt"));
br.readLine();
```

as well as [.skip()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29) method

```
br.skip(100 /* */);
```